# Bootstrap 5 Accordion Button Center Align and Line break

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 questions on this code I am using from bootstrap 5.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se14nh5y/)

1. How do I align the header to the center of the button?

   ```
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed text-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <h2>ABC</h2><br /><p>Date Time</p>
    </button>
   ```

I tried inserting text-center to accordion-header and accordion-button but still, it is not aligned.

2. How do I remove the arrow on the right?

I inspected the element and realized that it is in :: after which could not be seen in the HTML code. I like to check if I can move this by doing some CSS tweak?

3. Any idea how i can introducce a line break bewtween the `<h2>ABC</h2>`and the `<p>Date Time</p>`? i tried adding `<br />` but still doesnt separate them.

I have seen some examples for bootstrap 4 and it works to an extent but in bootstrap 5, certain classes changed the name and it is way more stubborn.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add this code in your css , hope this help for you

```
.accordion-button{
    display:block;
}
```

**JsFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/gw8yns17/

Comment: Doing this removes the accordion expansion icon

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do what you want:

class: `d-block text-center`

```html
<button 
  class="accordion-button d-block text-center" 
  type="button" 
  data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
  data-bs-target="#collapseOne" 
  aria-expanded="true" 
  aria-controls="collapseOne"
>
  Testimonials
</button>
```

Comment: This works but seems to remove the arrow of the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine and will not remove the accordion arrow:

```
<h2 class="accordion-header">
<button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <span class="d-block w-100 text-center">
            ABC
            <br>
            Date Time
        </span>
</button>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Force the child element width with `class="w-100 text-center"`

```
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
 <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <h2 class="w-100 text-center">Rechercher une <b>demande</b></h2>
 </button>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS - Redeem the arrow:

```css
    .accordion-button::after {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    }
```